# How to add multiply styles document.documentElement.style.setProperty (js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm adding dark and light theme, I changed bg-color, but can't change text color

**Css** (I don't have variables)

```
body {
    color: var(--text-color, white);
    background-color: var(--background, #181818);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**Js**

```
document.getElementById('dark_theme').addEventListener
    ('click', () => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty
        ('--background', '#181818');
        ('--text-color', 'white')

    })
document.getElementById('light_theme').addEventListener
    ('click', () => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty
        ('--background', 'white');
        ('--text-color', 'black')
        
    })
```

Comment: You need to call setProperty again.

Comment: Make the styles "relative" to a theme-specific class on the `<html>` or `<body>` element and just change that class: `<html class="dark_theme">`, `html.dark_theme body { ... }` (even easier with nesting/SASS): https://jsbin.com/quwilahari/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd have added a class to the body element such as ".darkTheme" and that'd be only one line of JS and a faster program. The snippet below shows you how to do it, just a point that you can have the body inherit a theme (class) by default.

```js
document.getElementById('dark_theme').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.add("darkTheme");
  document.body.classList.remove("lightTheme");
});
document.getElementById('light_theme').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.remove("darkTheme");
  document.body.classList.add("lightTheme");
});
```

```css
body {
  color: var(--text-color, white);
  background-color: var(--background, #181818);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body.darkTheme {
  --background: #181818;
  --text-color: white;
}

body.lightTheme {
  --background: white;
  --text-color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id="dark_theme"> Apply the dark theme </button>
  <button id="light_theme"> Apply the light theme </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Although if you don't seek this way, I can help you with your own.

The point is your JS code ends the setProperty method with ");" and you can't expect your code to work as *"('--text-color', 'white')"* makes no sense.

You can edit your JS like this:

```
let myDocStyle = document.documentElement.style;
document.getElementById('dark_theme').addEventListener('click', () => {
  myDocStyle.setProperty('--background', '#181818');
  myDocStyle.setProperty('--text-color', 'white');
});
document.getElementById('light_theme').addEventListener('click', () => {
  myDocStyle.setProperty('--background', 'white');
  myDocStyle.setProperty('--text-color', 'black');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement, by itself, does nothing:

```
('--text-color', 'white')
```

(It's not even really a *statement*, just an *expression* whose result is ignored.)

The line before it isn't a *complete statement* in JavaScript.  Newlines/whitespace aren't important to the interpreter.  (But are *very important* to humans for readability.)  *Both* of the previous lines are a statement:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty
('--background', '#181818');
```

That statement is terminated by a semi-colon.  Personally I prefer the readability of a single line in this case:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background', '#181818');
```

If you want to execute multiple such statements, you need the whole statement:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background', '#181818');
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--text-color', 'white');
```

In this case you may want to stick with single-line statements for readability, so you can easily see where one statement ends and another begins.

If you have many such statements and want to reduce their length for brevity and/or readability, you can store the reference in a variable:

```
const style = document.documentElement.style;
style.setProperty('--background', '#181818');
style.setProperty('--text-color', 'white');
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use classList methode like this:

```js
    function changeTheme(){
        document.body.classList.remove("theme1");
        document.body.classList.add("theme2");
    }
```

```css
.theme1:{
    background:white;
    color:black;
}

.theme2:{
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i add dark and light mode to work without any error.

```js
let toggle = document.querySelector("#toggle")
let body = document.querySelector("body")

toggle.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
if(body.classList.contains("dark")) return body.classList.remove("dark")

return body.classList.add("dark")
})
```

```css
body{
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}

.dark{
background: black;
}

.title{
color: gray;
}

.dark .title{
color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body class="dark">
<button id="toggle"> dark/light </button>
<div class="title">
<h1> My Title</h1>
</div>
</body>
```